# Angular 2 SCSS styling

Tags: angular, scss-lint

I wrote scss mixin in main root file style.scss. when i try to access it in my home component it gives me error as No mixin named gradient.

Please help do i need to include styles.scss file in my component

```css
//linear gradient color
$from: #1279C9;
$to: #439FE7;

@mixin gradient($from, $to) {
    /* fallback/image non-cover color */
    background-color: $from;
  
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  
    /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1+ */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from($from), to($to));
  
    /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  }
```

Comment: if still not working, share it some where and share url

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the mixin in some master file in some easy-to-access location (let say /app/scss) and then import that master into the component style where it should be user like

```
@import '~app/scss/master'
```

Mixin should be recognized then.

Comment: i added thart in style.scss. still do i need to include that file?

Comment: Not sure if you really have to, that would depend on the compilation / bundling process ... but since I know nothing about your app and its building sequence I can only presume that if the name is not recognized, you have to make the app to see the source file ...

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI? If you define some variable, let say $red: #FC625D; in your style.scss can u use it in your component style, let say you have h1 { color: $red } ?

Comment: Do you really need that mixing actually? It just prefixes the gradient ... autoprefixer will handle that ... most browser ever do not use prefixes for gradient backround ...

Answer (score 0):

i did this using master.scss file and i included this file in every components scss file

Comment: I do not get the point of your answer, is it just saying that it worked, or you mistyped this and by mistake posted an answer rather than comment? I am not sure if my answer helped you or I failed to help you.